# Why aren't elastomer suspensions still used on economy cars?

Tags: materials, automotive-engineering, springs

Classic Mini Coopers used a hollow rubber cone as a combination spring and damper in a pushrod suspension. Why aren't simple elastomer springs still used in cheaper cars? Formula 500 cars use an even simpler rubber spring: a small "hockey puck" with adjustable preload.

[image: Mini Cooper suspension]

Comment: One good reason is that they had to be replaced every 5 years or so, otherwise the suspension lowered itself by a few inches as the rubber cone sagged, and the handling was rubbish. No modern car owner would tolerate that sort of maintenance. Coil springs last for the life of the car. Coil spring replacement suspensions for classic Minis are available - I wonder why, if the original design was so good!

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised it's not popular for karts as an easily tunable alternative to a flexible frame.